# Enviar dados de um formulario por email

Tags: android, email, envio-de-email

Ola gostaria de saber como enviar dados de um formulário por e-mail. sendo que nesse formulário contem uma imagem de perfil.
exemplo:

foto perfil:
nome:
idade:
sexo:

depois de salvar esses dados queria dar um clique longo sobre a opção salva e abrir a opção compartilhar por e-mail e então enviasse esses dados para outras pessoas.

Comment: Você é programador?

Comment: resumindo voce precisa que alguem faça o app para voce certo? ai so tem a descricao do que precisa ser feito, nao fala onde voce esta com dificuldade nem nada do tipo. ate por que são varios processos e etapas, o android por si só não envia email. o maximo que ele faz é abrir o app de mail com o corpo da mensgem preenchido.

Comment: Você já fez umas perguntas no site, e você sabe como funciona. Ninguém vai te dar um tutorial de como fazer tal coisa. Aqui você terá respostas para perguntas com um mínimo de esforço em alguma tentativa.

Comment: ola  @durtto , não pedir para fazer apenas gostaria de sabe como enviar esses dados...uma vez que ja tenho pronto todo esse formulário.

Comment: Apenas quero saber como enviar esses dados por email de forma que carregue essas infomaçoes como anexo

Comment: Se você já tem o formulário pronto, posta o código aí. A forma de envio depende bastante do que você já tem.

Comment: @MarcosMT6 fica mais facil para ajudar vc se postar seu código e mostrar onde esta tendo dificuldades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer passar essas informações para qualquer aplicativo instalado com funcionalidade de envio de e-mail, utilize: `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. Nesse link abaixo tem um exemplo bem elaborado, fazendo a captura dos dados do formulário e compartilhando esses dados com outro app.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465796/will-anyone-give-example-for-sending-mail-with-attachment-in-android